# Calling a scenario in another feature file by scenario name

Tags: karate, reusability

Hi I have the following feature file:

checkout.feature

```
  Scenario: checkout items in basket 
    * call read('classpath:login.feature@[call by scenario name]')
    Given path '/checkout'
    And request {"items":{"biscuits": 1,"apples": 2}}
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

Before checking out the items in the basket, I would like to call the login.feature by scenario name (log into app with credentials), without the use of a tag. Could you please tell me the syntax in order to do so?

login.feature

```
  Scenario: log into app with credentials 
    Given path '/login'
    And request {"userDetails":{"userName": 1,"apples": 2}}
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

I have read https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-tag-selector but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't have a tag. Add this line above the `Scenario` in `login.feature`:

```
@foo
```

And then you just do this:

```
* call read('classpath:login.feature@foo')
```

Comment: Hey Peter - I understand that it's possible to reference a scenario via tag. I wanted to know if there was a way to reference the scenario via scenario name?

Comment: @zwanchi101 no, we will never support it for `call` because names can have spaces and special characters

Comment: @zwanchi101 : Did u get any solution for it am too stuck on the same i need to call with scenario name or scenario description, please add ur comments if u have any solution

Answer (score 1):

Feature1

```
@exampleTag
Scenario: Name
```

Feature2

```
def result = call read('classpath:pathFromSourceRoot/Feature1.feature@exampleTag')
```