# How to ignore a scenario in called feature Karate?

Tags: karate

`@ignore` tag will not work if we called the feature file from other feature. Is there any alternative how to ignore specific scenario in called feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have multiple scenarios in called features. Re-use is normally needed for very specific needs, such as setting up a test. Also please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

That said, you can see if the "call by tag" approach helps:

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call-tag-selector

And refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971678/143475